# Complexity of walking through graph by taking path with biggest weight

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have a graph, I want to walk through the graph (not necessary through all vertices), always taking path with greates weight. I cannot go through same vertex twice, I stop if there are no more moves I can make. What is the complexity? I assume it's "n" (where n is number of vertices) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't go through the same vertice twice, your upper bound for edge traversals is n.
It's easy to think of examples where that would be a *tight* bound (a single chain of vertices connected for example).

However, keep in mind that complexity is for a given algorithm, not a general task, you haven't described your algorithm or how your graph is organized, so this question doesn't have any meaning.

If for example the graph is a clique, perhaps picking the highest weight edge for each traversal would itself take n computation steps (if the edges are kept in an unsorted list kept in each vertice), making the naive algorithm O(n^2) in this case. Other representations may have different complexity, but require different algorithms.

**EDIT**

If you're asking about finding the path with greatest **overall** weight (which may require you in some traversals to pick an edge that doesn't have the highest weight), than the problem is NP-hard. If it had a polynomial algorithm, then you could take an unweighted graph and find the longest path (a known NP hard problem as jimifiki pointed), and solve it with that algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

From [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)

This problem is called the Longest Path Problem, and is NP-complete.

Comment: No, the longest path doesn't care about weights, you just have to pick the right edge to prevent yourself from reaching used vertices - that's the hard thing. Picking the heaviest edge is simple.

Comment: @Leeor, please. The longest path is a subset of the max-weight path instances. Thus the max-weight path is at least as complex. 
If longest path is NP-complete, the max-weight path is too.

Comment: Hmm. his question isn't very clear - I understood he was asking about always taking the edge with max weight, not maximizing the overall weight. In that case you're right of course, i'll edit.

Comment: @Leeor, I agree with you!